# ESP8266 still connects to wifi even after flashed with empty sketch

Tags: esp8266

So, my wifi is a hotspot password protected. I was developing a program until I decided to comment the ssid and passwords from it, to prevent the ESP from connecting to the internet. But then it still connected. After some debugging, I decided to upload an empty sketch. It still connects to the hotspot!

What is going on?! How does it still know my SSID and password when loaded with an empty sketch!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Espressif esp8266 SDK remembers the SSID and password on flash to start connecting immediately after boot. The WiFi channel is stored in the RTC memory (cleared on power down)

You can control this with [WiFi.persistent()](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/generic-class.html?highlight=persistent#persistent) and [WiFi.setAutoConnect()](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/station-class.html?highlight=autoconnect#setautoconnect).

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be it!